# Unable to use Bootstrap solutions to center menu that doesn't use navbar class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, centering

NOTE: You can see an image of the correctly formatted menu text vs the shifted menu text at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7PEj.png

2nd EDIT: 
Note added page source code from original page. HTML for this question originally was for the Header.php file. The 2nd EDIT HTML is from the page source code prior to suggested changes were made — most notably, the "span3" and "logo" divs have been taken out of the header HTML because they were preventing the menu from moving over to the left. I had posted this code in an earlier question that went unanswered.

Hope this might help with finding out why the submenu text won't go in the boxes. Thanks.

```
<header style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px; ">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="span3">
    <div id="logo">
            <a href="SITE URL">

                                    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span9">
        <!-- Mobile Menu -->
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"><span class="menu-icon"></span></a>

        <!-- Standard Menu -->
        <div id="menu">
            <ul id="menu-nav" class="sf-js-enabled">
            <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-14"><a href="SITE URL">Home<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-266"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=252">About<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=11">Blog<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-198"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=196">SITE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a>
<ul class="sub-menu sf-js-enabled" style="float: none; width: 20em; display: none; visibility: hidden; ">
<li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-569" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-565" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-565" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-portfolio menu-item-454" style="white-space: normal; float: none; width: 100%; "><a href="SITE NAME?portfolio=PAGE" style="float: none; width: auto; ">PAGE NAME<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="SITE URL?page_id=257">Contact<mark class="bar"></mark></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

@davidpauljunior Thanks for your quick help. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me after trying step-by-step several times. I think I know why it didn't work for me. I entered the markup from the theme's header file, but I uploaded the CSS from the TB CSS instead of the theme's CSS, which most likely has been tweaked in its own right. If you would please forgive that goof, I'm going to take another crack at it below. I would have done this in the comments, but it doesn't allow for such long code. Note sections marked EDIT. Hope I haven't squandered any goodwill. Thanks.

––––––––––––––––––––––

I have a WP theme based on Twitter Bootstrap, and the theme's author did not use the navbar class for the menu. Instead, it just uses header and #menu and slight variations for the navigation. My problem is that the standard menu consisted of two parts: a logo on the left and the menu to the right of it, aligned to the right.

I am not using a logo, so I would like the menu to be centered horizontally. I've tried dozens of things I've found here for centering, but none work. I thought it might have to do with the fact that the theme used a "span3" for the logo. I went to the header.php file and edited it out. The menu has now moved all the way over to the left alignment where the logo place should be. That's progress, but I still have found no way to center the logo in the top. I've tried applying the many code bits for centering that were used for "navbar" but none do the trick.

Here's the header php markup after I've deleted the logo divs.

```
<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row">



        <div class="span9"  style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <!-- Mobile Menu -->
            <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"><span class="menu-icon"></span></a>

            <!-- Standard Menu -->
            <div id="menu">
                <ul id="menu-nav">
                <?php 
                    if(has_nav_menu('primary_menu')) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary_menu', 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'link_after' => '<mark class="bar"></mark>' ) ); 
                    }
                    else {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">No menu assigned!</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- End Header -->

<!-- Mobile Navigation Mobile Menu -->
<div id="navigation-mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul id="menu-nav-mobile">
                <?php 
                    if(has_nav_menu('primary_menu')) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary_menu', 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); 
                    }
                    else {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">No menu assigned!</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Navigation Mobile Menu -->
```

The rest of the menu is under the class "span9"— I tried to see if it would help to change it to "span12" but it didn't do any good. I'm very new to this, but I'm trying to understand. Should I be doing this in the header.php AND in the CSS style file? Or can this all be done in either the markup in the header file or just in CSS customization?

EDIT: Here's the CSS stylesheet section for the header [EDIT-from the theme itself]:

```
/* Navigation */

#menu {
    float: right;
}

/* Sub-Menu */

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
    line-height: 160px;
    z-index: 40;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

#menu ul a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #B2B2B6;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul li:hover { visibility: inherit; }

#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999em;
    width: 220px !important;
}

#menu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

#menu ul ul li .bar {
    display: none;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul,
#menu ul li.sfHover ul {
    top: 160px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 99;
}

#menu ul a:hover,
#menu ul li.sfHover a,
#menu > ul li.current-cat a,
#menu > ul li.current_page_item a,
#menu > ul li.current-menu-item a,
#menu ul li.current-page-ancestor a,
#menu ul li.current-menu-ancestor a {
    color: #56646F;
}

#menu ul li a .bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background: #F88A79;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.19s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.19s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: top 0.19s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: top 0.19s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

EDIT: And this is my customization of the menu to style it the way I wanted—and everything operates and looks fine this way, just that it's not centered. (sorry, I don't know the best way to go about showing all this—I hope I'm not violating some etiquette here by not posting it properly):

```
#menu {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu-nav {
text-align: center;
}

#menu menu-nav ul  {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}

#menu ul { 
display:inline-block; 
}

#menu ul { 
display:inline; 
zoom:1;
}

#menu ul li a .bar {
height: 50px;
}

#menu ul li.sfHover ul {
    top: 100px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 99;
}


#menu-nav{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}



#menu ul a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul .sub-menu li a {
    color: #989898;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 20px;

    -webkit-transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this. I've been trying for weeks to get this to work. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the way this question developed and developed and developed, I've opted to add another answer.

The first problem here is that your HTML is incorrect.  There is an extra `<li>` and `<ul>` in there.  I've commented them out in my demo at the bottom.

Second, there's a lot of confusion around the styles.
You also have errors with selectors, like `#menu menu-nav ul` (missing a `.`).

I'm taking it that ***the theme is something that can't be touched, and the aim is to overwrite that with your own theme customisations***.  That being the case:

1. Remove all inline styles, it's bad practice.
2. Change your styles according to the CSS in the demo below.

http://jsbin.com/UVaZUki/1/edit

Comment: Yes, due to updates possibly breaking altered parts of the theme, it's safer to not alter actual theme code. I removed the inline styles as you suggested previously in the header.php. I pasted your new CSS in place of the previous. Mostly good. Introduced a few new problems, but able to fix a couple. But the big one is that the menu is now at the top of the header (should be at bottom-see image sample). It makes too much space between menu item and drop down — the drop down goes away when you stop hovering on the menu item. Can't find what it was in old code to put it back at header bottom.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what the extra ul and li tags would have been. I just copied and pasted that in from the source code of the page after Wordpress created the menu items. I haven't done any alteration of HTML except in the header.php, none in the page source code.

Comment: In the example link I gave it's the same as the image. Not much more I can do to help

Comment: I spotted the problem. It was in the #menu ul li. The line-height was set to "normal" instead of the original 160px. Changing that popped the menu right into place. A few minor style issues had to be dealt with, but they're all done. I'd say this is officially SOLVED!! Thank you, thank you! It looks and functions great! You can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/npUR0eT.png?1

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `span9` with `span12` and remove all *inline* styles.

Then, it's just some CSS tweaks.  **Add**:

```
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

and then **replace** the `float: left` with `display: inline-block` here:

```
#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; REMOVE */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  line-height: 160px;
  z-index: 40;
}
```

And **remove** this `last-child` style, it'll throw it slightly off center.

```
#menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

[Working demo here](http://jsbin.com/IdIwUFO/3/edit)

**NOTE:  I've only put the first nav in my demo.**

---

EDIT - For your updated code, see the following demo.  I've pasted the theme CSS in followed by your CSS.  I've removed a number of things, and added a few.  You declared a width of 90px on the `<ul>` which is odd, and you have an invalid selector `#menu menu-nav` - missing the `.`.

http://jsbin.com/IdIwUFO/6/edit

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Please forgive my goof. See edited question above for details. Your solution would not work because of my mistake.

Comment: You need IE7 support?

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time for this—and dealing with my missteps.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to finish…again, thank you. It's centered! 

But there is still a problem. All the sub-menus are messed up. The submenus now were only showing one sub-menu list item and the block of the sub-menu was in the correct position, but the text within the block is offset to the left by 50% (the hover accent color over the text is shifted too). I've tried going through the CSS line by line, but only successful with getting the rest of the hidden sub-menu blocks back (got rid of "overflow: hidden") Any ideas on getting the text shifted back in the blocks? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. Still didn't help the text in submenu box issue. The text of the submenu is still halfway outside the box to the left. I tried just copying and pasting your revised code into the theme because you made some additions and deletions that were hard to catch. I tried doing it by going line by line and making changes to your prior code. I also cleared the cache each time to make sure I was getting the page completely reloaded each time. Didn't help either way. Should I post CSS from a clean stylesheet so you can see what it normally looks like? It's so close to working out.

Comment: It's getting too convoluted.  It could be done easily from scratch, but writing styles over a theme is getting messy.  Show a picture of exactly what you want.

Comment: I would love to post a comparison image, but since I'm new, the site won't let me post any. My site is not live, so I don't have any URL to point to. I would gladly send the image to one of you if I knew how. If one of you sent your email address through this URL, it would reach me, and I could send the image for one of you to post. I'm sure it would be much more clear. http://www.babyblues.com/contact.html   Thanks.

Comment: You should use something like http://imgur.com/ to add an image then include a link here

Comment: Thanks for the imgur hint. I've edited the question to show the link to the image. The image shows the correctly formatted drop down menu items as they were pre-code-change for centering the menu. The image on the right is how it displays after using the code that centers the menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say 'from the theme itself', what do you mean?  Is this a Bootstrap theme you have?  Or is it a theme another developer wrote?  Are we trying to overwrite the theme styles, or are we editing the theme itself?

Comment: It is a theme I purchased based on TB. The image with the correct text in menu is from the theme's sample page. The image of my page is after adding all the custom CSS to a child theme to center the menu. So all the CSS changes I'm making are being made in the CSS editor of the theme, to customize the look. All with the exception of removing the logo references in the header.php file, inline styles and change the span to 12. 

Before, it looked great except I couldn't center the menu. Now that I've centered the menu, all the menu list items have gone to the left and don't fit in the boxes.

Comment: I guess that means I'm overwriting the theme styles. Sorry, I know this is really imposing on your good graces, but you have been so helpful. I really appreciate it.